How is a PR curve plotted?
Whilst reading Machine Learning by Zhi-Hua Zhou (pg 34-35), I was a little confused on the method used to plot a PR curve and was hoping you could help me become a little less confused.
In the book it states:

the samples that are most likely to be positive are at the top of the ranking
list, and the samples that are least likely to be positive are
at the bottom. Starting from the top of the ranking list, we can incrementally label the samples as positive to calculate the
precision and recall at each increment.

Does this mean that if we have say



Sample
Confidence
Prediction




Pos
0.9
pos


Pos
0.6
pos



and we have the following formulas,
$$P=\frac{TP}{TP+FP}$$ $$R =\frac {TP} {TP+FN}$$
that for each row we cumulatively calculate a new P and R? eg. is the first plot (1/(1+0),  1/(1+0))  and then for the second row 2? How is each point calculated?
I have read around and many other sources mention a threshold for confidence, whereby each plot point is a different threshold and the values for TP, FN, etc. are of the whole set at that threshold? Which method is correct? Or they actually the same?
Thanks for your time.

The true positive ($TP$), false positive ($FP$), and false negative ($FN$) rates are calculated from a confusiton matrix.  Consider the table below:
          In reality:
You say:      pos neg
      pos      55  34
      neg      56 255

The precision is: $P = 55 / (55+34) = 0.618$, and the recall is: $R = 55 / (55+56) = 0.495$.  So that gives you a point to plot $(0.495, 0.618)$.  What you need is all of the possible $PR$ points your model can offer to plot the curve.  (You also need them in order.)  So you need a confusion matrix for every point.  You do this by sorting your dataset of actual classes by the model's confidence.  Then you make the first confusion matrix by calling the single most confident pattern positive, and all the rest negative (irrespective of the actual prediction), and calculate $P$ and $R$.  Next you make a second confusion matrix by calling the top two positive, and all the rest negative.  You continue until your last confusion matrix consists of only calling the very bottom row as negative, and all those above it positive.  If you'd like, you can also make one calling everything positive and everything negative—that will simply connect the curve to the two corners of the plot.  You now have your series of points in order, and you can plot them and connect them with line segments.
